# Running geth in light node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I would like to run light nodes using geth, but I dont what version of geth is stable to that kind of node or even a sync mode fast node.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Geth even provides unstable versions. Some projects provide nightly builds or other versions which are simply the latest code version which might not be stable but all the more public versions are supposed to be stable. You can find the latest version information here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases so just take the version 1.9.13 (latest at the time of writing) and it should work just fine.

The same is true for both light and fast sync modes.

Comment: thanks a lot, for the response, I'm running a node using the version of geth 1.9.8 and it has already synced until 9,000,000 blocks but show all balance in 0, but retrieves all transactions and blocks info, but when I go to the geth's terminal I

Comment: when I go to the geth's terminal and type seth.syncing I see that currentBlock stayed stuck currentBlock: 9199934,
  highestBlock: 9199999,
  knownStates: 265726802,
  pulledStates: 265693765,
  startingBlock: 9199934
}

Comment: Now @LauriPeltonen now I got, my light node working like a charm  and waiting for the fast sync mode node, but there is a constraint that can no do a light node, what others do?

Comment: You can't mine on a light node, for example. Here are more details: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5975/what-are-the-types-of-nodes-in-ethereum

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, @Lauri Peltonen I already have my light nodes working but in fast sync mode does not work the version of geth 1.9.3 that you told me. I got these settings Geth
Version: 1.9.13-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.13
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/go  and I already downloaded all blockchain without errors or stoping the sync,  but at the end does not work, show me all tx details by by hash or other operations but wallet's balance = 0 does not work :(

Comment: Well that is a separate issue. Your original question was about what version is stable and I answered that. Please post a new question if you have further problems