# Difference between full node,light node and miner

Tags: nodes, terminology

I am in confusion of the terms full node, light node ,miner and non-mining/non-miner. Please help me differentiate

Comment: Related: [What is the parity light pruning mode?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/what-is-the-parity-light-pruning-mode)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A full node has the full blockchain downloaded and available. There are multiple pruning methods in clients that store different levels of the blockchain as well.

[Pruning Mode Differences](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/what-is-the-parity-light-pruning-mode)

A light node does not store the blockchain, but gets the parts it cares about from someone it trusts.

[Light Client Protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)

[Consensys Light Wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet)

To be a miner you need to run a full node, and also run a mining package. Some clients have mining built in, as well as other mining options.

[Geth Mining](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining)

[GPU Mining](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/gpu.html)