# How to use parity 1.4.2 with light-client mode?

Tags: parity, light-clients

I've tried to use the latest geth with `--light` mode. It gets new blocks not very fast, but I could send transactions successfully. So I think it's useful!

What command should run parity in this mode?

Answer (score 2):

Parity does not support light client mode, yet.

Older versions did have a `light` pruning mode, but that is [something different](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3332/87), and not to be confused with.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your actual question is provided in the previous post by 5chdn... (i.e. You can't.)

However, if you just want a way to sync (more) quickly, then in Parity you could try `parity --warp`, as explained in [this previous thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/what-is-paritys-warp-sync-and-why-is-it-faster-than-geth-fast).